# Vue router: return to top of page while having a transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, router

When I go to another `<router-link>` I always return to top, because that is how I set up my router:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import { routes } from '@/router/routes.js';

export const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        } else if (to.hash) {
            return { el: to.hash, behavior: 'smooth' };
        } else {
            return { top: 0 };
        }
    },
});
```

But because I have a transition in `<RouterView/>`, when I click on a `<router-link>`, I first see the return to `top: 0`, since the transition lasts `0.2s`, I am able time to see it.

I want to see the return to top only when I am already on the `<router-link>` that I clicked, but at the same time I also want to see the transition. Maybe there's a delay I can add or something else?

Here's what I have in App.vue:

```
 <template>
    <main>
        <RouterView #="{ Component }">
            <transition mode="out-in" name="fade">
                <component :is="Component" />
            </transition>
        </RouterView>
    </main>
</template>

<script setup></script>

<style lang="scss">
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: 0.2s;
}
</style>
```

Please, give a solution.